# Ruby on Rails How to reach dynamically created url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I have been working on a ruby on rails application. I need send a mail to users in one case. I have created the link like this.

```
<%= link_to "Edit detail", edit_product_detail_url(@user.reset_token,email: @user.email) %>
```

In the mail box it will be seen as fallows:

```
Edit detail
```

Some times users can't access linked connections through from their mail box Instead I want link to be seen as

```
http://0.0.0.0.:3000/products/:token/edit
```

How can I reach dynamically created link url ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you mention, in what particular case do you want to show a different URL?

Comment: Sorry, couln't get it

Comment: I want to show the exact url, but don't know how to do it

Comment: Using _url should work just fine.
Can you mention what URL is getting displayed now?

Comment: It's just "Edit detail"

Comment: Then just skip link_to and use 
`<%= edit_product_detail_url(@user.reset_token,email: @user.email) %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <%= link_to "Edit detail", edit_product_detail_url(@user.reset_token,email: @user.email) %>
```

Using link_to helper will generate the a anchor tag with following html:
     `<a href="http://0.0.0.0.:3000/products/:token/edit">Edit detail</a>`

If we want just the URL displayed, just
`<% edit_product_detail_url(@user.reset_token,email: @user.email) %>`
will work.